# how do you execute a function on a List of objects using LINQ

Tags: linq, foreach

I want to execute a function on all the objects within a List of objects using LINQ. I know i saw something similar on SO before but after several failed search attempts, i am posting this question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following if it is actually of type `List<T>`.

C#

```
var list = GetSomeList();
list.ForEach( x => SomeMethod(x) );
' Alternatively
list.ForEach(SomeMethod);
```

VB.Net

```
Dim list = GetSomeList();
list.ForEach( Function(x) SomeMethod(x) );
```

Unfortunately .ForEach is only defined on `List<T>` so it cannot be used on any general `IEnumerable<T>` type.  Although it's easy to code such a function

C#

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> del) {
  foreach ( var cur in source ) {
    del(cur);
  }
}
```

VB.Net

```
<Extension()> _
Public Sub ForEach(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal del As Action(Of T)
  For Each cur in source
    del(cur)
  Next
End Sub
```

With this you can run .ForEach on any `IEnumerable<T>` which makes it usable from practically any LINQ query.

```
var query = from it in whatever where it.SomeProperty > 42;
query.ForEach(x => Log(x));
```

**EDIT**

Note to use the .ForEach for VB.Net.  You must chose a function that returns a value.  It's a limitation of lambda expressions in VB.Net 9 (VS 2009).  But there is o work around.  Say you want to call SomeMethod which is a Sub.  Simply create a wrapper which returns an empty value

```
Sub SomeMethod(x As String) 
  ... 
End Sub

Function SomeMethodWrapper(x As String)
  SomeMethod(x)
  Return Nothing
End Function

list.ForEach(Function(x) SomeMethod(x)) ' Won't compile
list.ForEach(function(x) SomeMethodWrapper(x)) ' Works
```

Comment: i would like to take the first approach you have mentioned. does that works similarly in vb.net

Comment: @Vikram, yes you can.  I updated the code to include VB.Net samples.

Comment: System.Linq already provides an extension for IEnumerable<T> that gives you a .ToList() which you can use, right?

Comment: @Terry yes you can take that approach and it will work.  But it does force everything into a single in memory collection.  Nothing inherently wrong with that but generally people avoid it when using LINQ.

Comment: thanks for the adding the snippet, however when i try to use the syntax you have given for vb.net, it does not works. it does not even lets me compile.

Comment: this is what i tried. and when i try to write SomeMethod(x), it shows me blue underlining saying that "Expression does not produce value". 

Dim list = GetSomeList()
list.ForEach( Function(x) SomeMethod(x) )

Comment: @Vikram, that's because ForEach is a Sub and returns no value.  If you want to modify the items in the list and return a new one, use Select instead of ForEach

Comment: i dont want to return any value but simply load some child elements in the object

Comment: For the VB.Net sample: "Methods in a Module cannot be declared 'Shared'."